# Remove all formatting when copy and pasting with Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy-paste, vba7, vba6

In word there is the ability to `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Unformatted Text`, and I'd like to do this by default.

I've created a Macro that reads:

```
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
```

Which seems remove the original fonts something, but it doesn't remove **bold**, *italic*,:

- List items / bullet points
- Or [hyperlinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pastespecial)

**What do I need to add to my Macro to remove all formatting?**

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteandformat

Answer (score 0):

Hemphta,

If you truly want your default to be pasting w/plain text you just need to set that preference in the File->Options->Advanced dialog.
[image]

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have mentioned that I'm on a Mac. So I don't have the advanced settings options. I only have the Word > Preferences option.

Comment: Maybe you can select pasted text and use Selection.Clearformatting and selection.UnlinkFields?

Answer (score 0):

**How to Force Microsoft Word to Paste Always Without Formatting 2022**

1. Select text from some web page with various font sizes (to test how
   formatting will be removed later).
2. Open Word and select – **Tools > Macro > Record Macro…** – and name the macro for example – **PasteNoFormatting**
3. **Edit > Paste Special… > Unformatted Text > OK** – see how formatting from the web page is removed.
4. **Tools > Macro > Stop Recording**
5. **Tools > Customize Keyboard …** – select –  **Categories: > Macros** – select your own macro – **PasteNoFormatting** – and click in the empty box called – **Press new keyboard shortcut** – and press the keycombination you want like – **Command - V** – or – **Ctrl - V** –
   click – **OK** – to save your changes.
6. Now Microsoft Word will always
   automatically paste text content without unnecessary formatting simply with
   keycombination – **Command - V** – or – **Ctrl - V**
7. In case you want to paste something with formatting, you can still do it by using – **Edit > Paste Special…**